# Google place autocomplete in swift doesn't works perfectly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, google-places-api

I tried to make "place autocomplete" from google place and I copy paste the codes directly from the website here [google developer](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#use_the_fetcher) and I already set the api key too but the problem is why the results look so odd when I typing a place as you can see on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixf2l.png) it seems works but not perfect. here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class FetcherSampleViewController: UIViewController {

  var textField: UITextField?
  var resultText: UITextView?
  var fetcher: GMSAutocompleteFetcher?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None

    // Set bounds to inner-west Sydney Australia.
    let neBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.843366,
      longitude: 151.134002)
    let swBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.875725,
      longitude: 151.200349)
    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: neBoundsCorner,
      coordinate: swBoundsCorner)

    // Set up the autocomplete filter.
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .Establishment

    // Create the fetcher.
    fetcher = GMSAutocompleteFetcher(bounds: bounds, filter: filter)
    fetcher?.delegate = self

    textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 5.0, y: 0,
      width: self.view.bounds.size.width - 5.0, height: 44.0))
    textField?.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth
    textField?.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:",
      forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

    resultText = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 45.0,
      width: self.view.bounds.size.width,
      height: self.view.bounds.size.height - 45.0))
    resultText?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
    resultText?.text = "No Results"
    resultText?.editable = false

    self.view.addSubview(textField!)
    self.view.addSubview(resultText!)
  }

  func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    fetcher?.sourceTextHasChanged(textField.text!)
  }

}

extension FetcherSampleViewController: GMSAutocompleteFetcherDelegate {
  func didAutocompleteWithPredictions(predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
    let resultsStr = NSMutableString()
    for prediction in predictions {
      resultsStr.appendFormat("%@\n", prediction.attributedPrimaryText)
    }

    resultText?.text = resultsStr as String
  }

  func didFailAutocompleteWithError(error: NSError) {
    resultText?.text = error.localizedDescription
  }
}
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `prediction.attributedPrimaryText` is an attributed string. Try the following code

```
func didAutocompleteWithPredictions(predictions: [GMSAutocompletePrediction]) {
    let resultsStr = NSMutableAttributedString()
    for prediction in predictions {
        resultsStr.appendAttributedString(prediction.attributedPrimaryText)
        resultsStr.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
    }
    resultText?.attributedText = resultsStr
}
```